# Android: Retrieve contacts of accounts programmatically

Tags: android, contacts, account

I added the two google accounts on my emulator. Later I added contacts under each account. I  am able to get account using below link.

[What is the default Account Type / Name for contacts on Android Contact Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863653/what-is-the-default-account-type-name-for-contacts-on-android-contact-applicat)

Now how do I programmatically retrieve the contacts and its fields added under the accounts?

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ

Answer (score 0):

You can query the account specific contacts by querying the Raw contacts table by passing Account name and type in selection parameters