# How in single query to get photo, email and phone number of user

Tags: android

I'm using three different queries to get photo, email and phone number with following URI:

```
private final Uri mEmailUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
private final Uri mPhotoUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
private final Uri mPhoneUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
```

It takes too long to get records.
Is there any faster way to accomplish it?

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686110/android-contacts-provider-get-only-phone-contacts-with-all-emails