# Android Contacts - What are all the account types for android contacts?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contacts, android-contentresolver

When Contacts are stored in an android device, they are stored under a certain account type (and account name). These types include Sim, Device and Google account.
Does anyone know where I can find a list of all of these types?

Comment: No, as you can create your own... Edit: depends on when.... If you wana do this as hardcode then no, but you may list of account types at runtime

Comment: Have you tried looking at the contacts ContentProvider?

Comment: Do you know of a way I can programatically find the existing ones on a device Selvin?

Comment: Also, I am sure that there are some that are known, like SIM, Selvin,

Comment: Cricket, I have looked at the documentation as well as lots of other related documentation pages, and I found nothing relevant unfortunately.

Comment: Like sim? On devices without sim? I have edited my first comment... But still not all accounts use Contacts content provider.

Comment: How can I find a list of account types at runtime? I don't mind not finding accounts that do not use contacts content provider.

Answer (score 0):

Account Name/Type are not consistent through all Android devices. Every brand uses different account names for SIM and internal memory, as an example (and take in account the records there are copied to the database). You can know, though, the name/type for other providers, like Google, Facebook or Whatsapp.
Here [What is the default Account Type / Name for contacts on Android Contact Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863653/what-is-the-default-account-type-name-for-contacts-on-android-contact-applicat) it is explained how to get this fields.