# Howto retrieve all accounts availables for contacts?

Tags: android

I would like to programmatically retrieve all accounts on a android phone/tablet that are able to be used for contacts, ***without any previous knowledge of the existents accounts***.

I used **AccountManager** to retrieve all accounts, but this give me other accounts too (for example email accounts).

So I added **AccountManager.hasFeatures()** to select the only accounts that have the "**service_contacts**" feature, but in this way I only find the Google account and not others (for example on my phone I use Davdroid account for my contacts, and my program don't select this account).

So, where I'm wrong? Are there others API that I should use?
Can someone suggest me (maybe with some code as example) a way to the goal?

Thanks for any help

**EDITED:**

Sorry for my not perfect knowledge of english language, but I thought I explained well myself.

I don't want to retrieve an account that I already know, or by a type that I already know (getAccountsByType).
I want to deploy an Application on a phone **that I don't know**, that can have whatever account (maybe none Google account) **with no any previous knowledge**, and retrieve only that accounts able to be used for contacts (***they are the accounts that you can select in the Contacts application when you add a new contact***).

Maybe I'm wrong and I ask forgiviness for that, but I can't see this as a duplicated question, and I'm not able to understand how to use your answers to solve my very specific problem.

Thanks again for your answers

**SOLUTION:**

I used ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes() to select all sync adapters related to "**com.android.contacts**", so the code is (I used an EditText for display):

```
    private void getAccountsForContacts() {
    // Constants
    final String SYNC_AUTHORITY = "com.android.contacts";
    // Variables
    List<SyncAdapterType> okSyncs;
    SyncAdapterType[] mySyncTypes;
    AccountManager accountManager;
    Account[] tempAccounts;
    List<Account> allAccounts;
    String textAccounts;
    int i;
    int j;

    // Clear the text
    EditText editListAccounts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editListAccounts);
    editListAccounts.setText("");
    // Initialize all variables
    okSyncs = new ArrayList<SyncAdapterType>();
    allAccounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    textAccounts = "";
    // Get all sync adapters
    mySyncTypes = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
    if (mySyncTypes.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < mySyncTypes.length; i++) {
            // Select the only adapters for contacts
            if (mySyncTypes[i].authority.equals(SYNC_AUTHORITY)) {
                okSyncs.add(mySyncTypes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (okSyncs.size() > 0) {
        accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        // From sync get all related accounts
        for (i = 0; i < okSyncs.size(); i++) {
            tempAccounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(okSyncs.get(i).accountType);
            if (tempAccounts.length > 0) {
                for (j = 0; j < tempAccounts.length; j++) {
                    allAccounts.add(tempAccounts[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (allAccounts.size() > 0) {
        for (i=0; i<allAccounts.size(); i++) {
            textAccounts += allAccounts.get(i).toString();
        }
    } else {
        textAccounts = getResources().getString(R.string.main_accounts_not_found);
    }
    editListAccounts.setText(textAccounts);
}
```

I hope it can be useful for someone.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: If the API doesn't have the filter you want, filter the set that includes the accounts you want yourself.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/4863653/180100

Comment: Please, read again the edited post, and if you agree, remove the "duplicate" tag. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess this one could help you solving it by yourself and learning things that way

[AccountManager.getAccountsByType(java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAccountsByType(java.lang.String))